# Unable to find /etc/kubernetes/manifests on my machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

i am unable to find the manifests path on my local machine, however, when i am checking inside minikube's cluster, I am able to see. Any hint, how can i set up this directory on my local?

Comment: Why should it be there? Did you setup Kubernetes on that machine? What do you need that directory for?

Comment: @svenwltr I am trying to setup fluentd with EFK stack. I am following a documentation where it says to put the pod .yaml in that directory. https://dzone.com/articles/kubernetes-log-analysis-with-fluentd-elasticsearch

Comment: Then you have to put that file into the directoy in minikube. Minikube cannot access that directory on your local machine since it is a VM. Nevertheless for experimenting you can just do `kubectl apply -f fluentd-pod.yaml`.

Comment: @svenwltr: You mean to say, no need of putting that file in the directory and I can simply try putting it in any directory for experimenting?

Comment: @svenwltr: And how do i create that directory inside minikuebe? When i am doing minikube ssh, I am able to see the directory. However, I am unable to place the yaml file into it as 'vim' command doesn't work

Comment: You can put it into any directory when using `kubectl apply ...`. I guess using a text editor is out of topic here, but you could try `vi` or `nano` instead. Also I really recommend to go through some basic Kubernetes tutorials before continuing with this "documentation" since it doesn't aim for minikube.